# Oracle forms 6i insert image in word file

Tags: oracleforms

I need to take a microsoft word file and insert an image under It in a certain position (with delimited chars or someting like that). Then save that.
This is possible with Oracle Forms 6i? My database is 11G.
If this is not possible, can I read a certain amount of text under the word file and then put it into another, then save the new file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give some code you use to do this? And if there is an error the errormessage?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nightfox79, but I do not have an error, I just want to know if the Forms 6i can handle this (open a word file, insert an image under it and then save the document).

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't. But you can use Oracle Reports to make something that looks like your Word Doc, and then use your database to populate the specific data you need and save it wherever you want.

Otherwise if you're going to use Word, you need to setup the connection to your database in Word. But your question is a little too vague to give you a complete answer.